# C++ implementation of a gRPC generic proxy

Tags: proxy, grpc-c++

There doesn't seem to be any c++ implementation out there providing a gRPC genric proxy server.
Generic means here it is able to receive grpc client requests and forward them to a grpc server while being proto-agnostic.

The proxy should be proto-agnostic in the sense that it doesn't need to use any proto spec to operate, and most importantly, it doesn't need to know anything about the proto spec used by the client and server.
The proxy should be able to receive any grpc request from a client and forward it to a grpc server, also return back the response to the client.
The proxy should support all the different types of grpc services.
(a) Unary
(b) Client steaming
(c) Server streaming
(d) Bidirectional streaming

The proxy should work at the gRPC layer, not at the transport layer; meaning it can extrat some gRPC metadata, like the method name and the service name being invoked.

Possible solutions:

Option 1: Use the gRPC C++ classes grpc::AsyncGenericService and grpc::GenericStub
Option 2: If the option 1 is not possible, use a generic proto based on "Any" at the proxy; this proto should be compatible with any client/server proto. This would require to deserialize/serialize to Any.

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    package genericproxy;
    import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
    message ProxyGenericRequest {
      google.protobuf.Any request = 1;
    }
    message ProxyGenericResponse {
      google.protobuf.Any response = 1;
    }
    service ProxyGenericService {
      rpc ProxyGenericMethod(stream ProxyGenericRequest) returns (stream ProxyGenericResponse);
    }
```

The generic proxy can be used in a context, among others, where there is a need to use a third party library to create a gRPC channel with a third party service provider. Therefore, using TCP or HTTP2 proxy would not work in this case.

Using grpc::AsyncGenericService and grpc::GenericStub, I am trying to find an example code based on this solution.

Regarding solution 2, there is a need to prove that a proxy supporting a generic proto spec based on bi-ditrectional streaming, can spport unary, client streaming and server streaming flows.

Is there a known implementation (or a skeleton example) of a such a c++ grpc generic proxy?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a pre-existing example of such a proxy, but you can write your own.  It should be possible to write such a proxy using the gRPC generic APIs.

I suggest that you use the new C++ callback API described in [gRFC L67](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L67-cpp-callback-api.md).  You can find an example of using the generic callback client API in [this test](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/8fdfb22848639f33b12b02f967b640da42de7707/test/cpp/end2end/client_callback_end2end_test.cc#L264), and you can find an example of using the generic callback server API in [this test](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/8fdfb22848639f33b12b02f967b640da42de7707/test/cpp/end2end/hybrid_end2end_test.cc#L806).